# VSCODE, how to debug a cordova app running electron platform

Tags: cordova, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

I need to debug an Electron app on Windows. I used cordova to write my app and electron platform for windows version. What should i write in vscode's launch.json?

Is there a way to debug an electron app inside cordova with vscode?

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing a similar hurdle and am curious if you've found a solution. Thanks!

Comment: No... Nothing...